# Objective-C Block in Swift - Variable Missing?

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

Here's a block type that I am defining in objective-c

```
typedef void (^arrayBlock)(NSArray *blockArray);
```

I have an objective-c class with a method that uses this as a return block

```
-(void)loadTimesWithSuccessBlock:(arrayBlock)successBlock;
```

When I try to use this method in Swift, this is what autocomplete gives me.

```
let timeClockLibrarian = HMFTimeClockLibrarian()
timeClockLibrarian.loadTimesWithSuccessBlock { ([AnyObject]!) -> Void in
   //Where is blockArray?         
}
```

I'm assuming that [AnyObject]! is supposed to be the NSArray. But I don't see how I'm supposed to get access to that variable?

If I were to use this method in Objective-C I get a result like this:

```
[timeClockLibrarian loadTimesWithSuccessBlock:^(NSArray *blockArray) {
        //I can use the blockArray here :)
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[AnyObject]!` is indeed only the type of the variable; autocomplete didn't name it. You just need to do something like `(blockArray: [AnyObject]!)`.

```
let timeClockLibrarian = HMFTimeClockLibrarian()
timeClockLibrarian.loadTimesWithSuccessBlock { (blockArray: [AnyObject]!) -> Void in
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought. When I try to assign blockArray to a local variable i.e.{ var logEntries = [LogEntry() } using { self.logEntries = blockArray } it tells me "Cannot invoke 'loadTimesWithSuccessBlock' with an argument list of type '(([AnyObject]!) -> Void)'"

Comment: That's because the array is untyped and the assignment fails. You have different options depending on whether you use Xcode 6 or an Xcode 7 beta.

Comment: IIRC, that should be `self.logEntries = blockArray as [LogEntry]`.

Comment: Just tried it, and it wanted me to use as! instead of as. I'm not sure what that means, but it compiles now.

Comment: I wasn't sure which syntax was the correct syntax on Xcode 6, my bad. Glad it works. Also, at some point in the evolution of Xcode, it becomes possible to change the `typedef` on the Objective-C type to `void (^arrayBlock)(NSArray<LogEntry>* __nonnull blockArray)` or something along these lines, which lets Swift bridge the argument into a `[LogEntry]` without further complications.

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
let timeClockLibrarian = HMFTimeClockLibrarian()
timeClockLibrarian.loadTimesWithSuccessBlock { blockArray in
   doSomething(blockArray)
}
```

If you want to refer to weak self use this:

```
let timeClockLibrarian = HMFTimeClockLibrarian()
timeClockLibrarian.loadTimesWithSuccessBlock { [weak self] blockArray in
   self?.doSomething(blockArray)
}
```

You may also want to get rid of implicit unwrapping. If so, specify nullability in Obj-C code:

```
typedef void (^arrayBlock)(nullable NSArray *blockArray);
```